# Filter REST $resource data by $routeparams

Tags: angularjs, rest

I am using Angular to populate a few pages with REST data and have a list of articles for which I want a link to show the article details for that article. Basically, I need to filter the REST call I use for an individual article by the routeparam that is passed to it.

It appears to be passing the routeparam as expected, but I am having some challenges getting the REST call to work on my details page (articles.html), and I suspect that I am not getting/matching the ID in my REST call to the ID passed by the routeparam. My first REST call works for the categories.html page which lists all articles. I am using Angular's ngResource API with $resource. Here is the applicable code:

app.js (routing)

```
var pfcModule = angular.module('pfcModule', ['ngRoute', 'pfcServices', 'pfcControllers']);

pfcModule.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.
    when('/home', { templateUrl: './views/home.html'}).
    when('/categories', { templateUrl: './views/categories.html', controller: 'pfcCtrl' }).
    when('/articles/:articleID', { templateUrl: './views/articles.html', controller: 'pfcCtrl2' }).
    otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
}]);
```

services.js (REST Call)

```
var pfcServices = angular.module('pfcServices', ['ngResource'])

pfcServices.factory('pfcArticles', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
      return $resource('https://pfc.azure-mobile.net/tables/articles/:articleID', {});
  }]);
```

controllers.js (Controllers)

```
var pfcControllers = angular.module('pfcControllers', []);

pfcControllers.controller('pfcCtrl', ['$scope', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, pfcArticles) {
$scope.data = pfcArticles.query();
}]);

pfcControllers.controller('pfcCtrl2', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'pfcArticles', function ($scope, $routeParams, pfcArticles) {
$scope.data2 = pfcArticles.get({ articleID: $routeParams.articleID });
}]);
```

categories.html (partial, working as expected)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Link</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="article in data">
            <td>{{article.id}}</td>
            <td>{{article.articletitle}}</td>
            <td>{{article.articlecategoryid}}</td>
            <td><a href="#articles/{{article.id}}">Link</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

articles.html (partial, not working as I expect it to be filtered by the ID passed by the routeparam)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="article in data2">
            <td>{{article.id}}</td>
            <td>{{article.articletitle}}</td>
            <td>{{article.articlecategoryid}}</td>
            <td>{{article.articlesummary}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researching, I adjusted my articles.html partial to not have a repeat as follows, and it is working:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Category ID</th>
            <th>Summary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>{{data2.id}}</td>
            <td>{{data2.articletitle}}</td>
            <td>{{data2.articlecategoryid}}</td>
            <td>{{data2.articlesummary}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```